# Swift 2 Correct way to get level of any object game, protocol? struct? extension?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2

This is my first game, and I'm new on swift and sprite kit.

I must have a level for each class that needs get level. Like car lev1 car lev 2 etc. I have read about `protocol extension` etc, witch is the best way to approach level management?

I have tried to use LevelTraker as extension of this protocol:

```
protocol LevelTracker { 
     typealias    TypeUnit: TypeGame
     var         nameClass: String! {get set}           
     var     currentLevel : Int {get set} 
     mutating func levelIncreases()
}
```

but with extension, i must write 3 var each class that needs level.
i try the same extension LevelTraker with struct LevelTraker:

```
func getClassName (theClass:AnyObject) -> String {
     let name = _stdlib_getDemangledTypeName(theClass); return name}

protocol TypeGame {}

enum transportType : TypeGame {
    case ground, sea, air
}

struct LevelTracker {
    var sender: AnyObject
    var TypeUnit: TypeGame

    private func getSaveFileWhitName() -> String {
        let saveWithName = getClassName(sender) + "." + String(TypeUnit)
        return saveWithName
    }

    var currentLevel : Int {
        get {
            let stringName = getSaveFileWhitName()
            let returnValue : Int = dataBase.read(stringName) as? Int ?? 1    //Check for first run of app, if = nil, set = 1
            return returnValue
        }
        set (newValue) {
            let stringName = getSaveFileWhitName()
            let level : Int = self.currentLevel
            let val = newValue
            if (newValue > level) {dataBase.write(val, key: stringName)}
        }
    }

    mutating func levelIncreases() {self.currentLevel++}
    ///SERVE SOLO PER SVILUPPO
    mutating func RESETLEVEL() {dataBase.write(1, key: getSaveFileWhitName())}

}
```

To use: (thanks @Krzak)

```
class car  {
    init () {
        let level = LevelTracker(sender: self, TypeUnit: transportType.ground).currentLevel
    }
}
```

But I don't want modify all init object that use level, and the super super class in common, some class don't have propriety level.

Comment: I do not think you want to be doing a protocol,  protocols with extensions should be used on objects that have no relation to each other, but still conform to some kind of rules.  What you should be doing, is creating a base class called `Level`,  and have all your sub classes  inherit from it

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you have compiler error is in your last line. You're missing the `.ground`

I'm not sure how you're thinking though that this will work, shouldn't it be `var`?

```
var level = LevelTracker(sender: self, TypeUnit: transportType.ground).currentLevel
```

Comment: Thanks this was a oversight. But i think there is a smarter way to manage level... may be i've found something, I'll post my solution soon. thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I am reading it sounds like you are doing this:

```
class Level : AnyObject
{
   private func getSaveFileWhitName() -> String {
        let saveWithName = getClassName(sender) + "." + String(TypeUnit)
        return saveWithName
    }

    var currentLevel : Int {
        get {
            let stringName = getSaveFileWhitName()
            let returnValue : Int = dataBase.read(stringName) as? Int ?? 1    //Check for first run of app, if = nil, set = 1
            return returnValue
        }
        set (newValue) {
            let stringName = getSaveFileWhitName()
            let level : Int = self.currentLevel
            let val = newValue
            if (newValue > level) {dataBase.write(val, key: stringName)}
        }
    }

    mutating func levelIncreases() {self.currentLevel++}
    ///SERVE SOLO PER SVILUPPO
    mutating func RESETLEVEL() {dataBase.write(1, key: getSaveFileWhitName())}

}

class car : Level
{
    init () {
        let level = self.currentLevel
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. But this isn't what i'm looking for. I've a superclass (SKSpriteNode) and other children class. For example Car and Tree. Car has the level, tree no. I must use a protocol because car can't have 2 super class.

Comment: So you make level extend skspritenode

Comment: but if i do this, the tree class has the level extension and i don't want

Comment: no it won't,   `Tree` can subclass `SKSpriteNode`, `Car` can subclass `Level` that subclasses `SKSpriteNode`

Comment: tree and car in my game have the same super class like AllNode

Comment: then you make level extend AllNode,  I am assuming allNode extends SKSprite

Comment: protocol extensions should only be used when 2 objects have no family in common,  The main point of protocols is to make a blue print of your object.  If you have a family tree going, you should be subclassing,  but if say you have a protocol that attaches to a string and an skspritenode, and you need them to have the same functionality,  then you use a protocol extension

Comment: but if I use "protocol extensions should only be used when 2 objects have no family in common" is enough to subclass each class with different super class.

Comment: I've found a solution that for me is what i want. I'm happy if you can 
comment my solution! :) thank

Comment: huh? no they still have the same lineage

Comment: Then you need to change your question from "Correct Way" to "Way that makes me happy"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100316/discussion-between-simone-pistecchia-and-knight0fdragon).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I'm happy to have some comment.

```
protocol TypeGame {}

enum transportType : TypeGame {
    case car, bus, trak
}

protocol LevelTracker {
    var         nameClass: String! {get}
    var     currentLevel : Int {get set}
    mutating func levelIncreases()
}

extension LevelTracker {
    var currentLevel : Int {
        get {/*set to DB*/ return 1}
        set (newValue) {/*set to DB*/}
    }

    mutating func levelIncreases() {self.currentLevel++}}
```

A protocol only for transport object:

```
protocol Transport : LevelTracker {}
```

Ok, now my (simplified) class are:

```
class AllNode  {//SKSpriteNode
    init(){}
}

class TransportGame:AllNode, Transport {
    var nameClass : String! = "Transport"

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.nameClass = nameClass + "." + getClassName(self)}
}

class Car : TransportGame {}
class miniCar : Car {}
class Bus: TransportGame {}
class Tree: AllNode {}

var carOne = Car()
let levelCar = carOne.currentLevel

var busOne = Bus()
let levelBue = busOne.currentLevel

var treeOne = Tree()
tree.currentLevel    //ERROR YUPPI!!!! :)
```

Now the tree class can't access to level!
What do you think about this solution?

Comment: why would it?  tree has no access to the protocol.  Tree -> AllNode -> SKSpriteNode

Comment: what is level, because right now car and bus have its own level,  do you want this